# Is it true that the transpose of a matrix is the dual map in any basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

For self adjoint operators, we know that the Hermitian adjoint of the matrix is the adjoint of the operator but this is only true if we choose orthonormal basis for the matrix.  So I was wondering whether we need a specific basis in order for the statement "transpose of a matrix is the dual map" to be true?

Answer (score 5):

Let $V$ be a (finite dimensional) vector space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$.  Let $\varphi:V \rightarrow V$ be the linear map.  Let $x_1,\dots, x_n$ be any basis.  Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be the matrix representation of $\varphi$ with respect to $x_1,\dots, x_n$.  Let $\varphi^t$ denote the adjoint of $\varphi$ with respect to $\langle\cdot,\cdot \rangle$. Let $B=(b_{ij})$ be the matrix representation of $\varphi^t$ with respect to the same basis. Let $G$ be the $n\times n$ matrix defined by
$$
G_{ij}=\langle x_i,x_j\rangle
$$
Note $G$ is symmetric because the inner product is symmetric. Let $e_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $i=1,\dots, n$ denote the standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^n$ expressed as column vectors.  Then
$$
\langle \varphi x_i,x_j\rangle = (Ae_i)^TGe_j=e_i^TA^TGe_j = (A^TG)_{ij}
$$
and
$$
\langle x_i,\varphi^t x_j\rangle= e_i^T G(Be_j)=e_i^TGBe_j=(GB)_{ij}
$$
Since
$$
\langle \varphi x_i,x_j\rangle=\langle x_i,\varphi^t x_j\rangle,
$$
we have
$$
(A^TG)_{ij}=(GB)_{ij}.
$$
Hence, $A^TG=GB$ which means
$$
B=G^{-1}A^TG.
$$
On the other hand, if we started with an **orthonormal basis**, then $G=I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix and the above equation simplifies to $B=A^T$, that is, the matrix representation of $\varphi^t$ is the transpose of that of $\varphi$.